# Python lookup dictionary by value in list and return a different value from that dictionary

Tags: python

I've been trying to figure out how to do this elegantly in a single liner as an IF statement, but nothing having much luck.

I have the following - a lookup value, lets say VOLVO and then a list of dictionaries which has various cars and their attributes, e.g.

```
car_list = [{'MODEL': 'VOLVO', 'COLOUR': 'RED', 'MANUAL': True},
            {'MODEL': 'FORD', 'COLOUR': 'BLUE', 'MANUAL': False}]
```

So what I would like to achieve is an IF statement that says: IF VOLVO IS MANUAL. So essentially using the VOLVO lookup to then return the value for the MANUAL key.

Hope that makes sense. I know it can be achieved by something like this:

```
result = next(item for item in car_list if item["MODEL"] == "VOLVO")
if result['MANUAL']:
    pass
```

but if possible I'd like to do it cleanly in a one line IF statement.

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions!

Comment: I dont really get it, why can't you do a normal for loop on the values in `car_lsit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to get all Volvos:

```
[car for car in car_list if car['MODEL'] == 'VOLVO']
```

Then, presuming the list has only one Volvo, you want the first (and only) car in the list:

```
[car for car in car_list if car['MODEL'] == 'VOLVO'][0]
```

Then, you want the value of MANUAL for that car:

```
[car for car in car_list if car['MODEL'] == 'VOLVO'][0]['MANUAL']
```

Comment: Cheers John, just what I was after!

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you this way:

```py
car_list = [{'MODEL': 'VOLVO', 'COLOUR': 'RED', 'MANUAL': True},
            {'MODEL': 'FORD', 'COLOUR': 'BLUE', 'MANUAL': False}]

for car in car_list:
    if car.get('MANUAL',-1) == True:
        print('yes')
        pass
```